# cumulative Impulse Response Functions in R, error?

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am trying to calculate impulse response functions using `vars` package of Bernhard Pfaff. I am getting somehow confusing results.

Running the following code:

```
plot(irf(vecm.r1, impulse = c("heat"), response = "gdp",cumulative = T)$irf$heat,type="l")
```

I will get the following IRF graph:
[image]
Running the following code:

```
plot(irf(vecm.r1, impulse = c("heat","power"), response = "gdp",cumulative = T)$irf$heat,type="l")
```

I will get the following IRF graph:
[image]

Note that in both cases, I am plotting the **cumulative IRFs** of gdp to heat. However, I see difference in the plots - there should not be any difference. Adding `"power"` should not affect the way IRFs are calculated for the first variable.

Has anyone experienced such an issue? or If you think my simple code is incorrect, do please comment below. I would appreciate any comments.